# Update the large table takes a lot of time without any sucess

Tags: plsql, oracle19c

I have recently added a new column to the Oracle table with 715476364 records and 37 columns. The new column name is b_id.
We have another table,**b_id_list**, which has **b_id** value and I have to use that table to update the new column. *the_table* and *b_id_list* have a common column named **id**; so I use this pl/sql query:

```
set serveroutput on;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('START');
FOR rec in 
 (
  select /*+parallel(10)*/ distinct date_m td from the_table order by td
 )
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(rec.td);
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'update /*+parallel(10)*/ the_table a
        set (b_id)=(select b.b_id b_id from b_id_list b where 
        substr(a.id,12)=to_char(b.id)) 
        where exists (select 1 from b_id_list b where substr(a.id,12)=to_char(b.id)) and date=to_date(rec.td,''YYYYMMDD'')';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'commit';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The table is partitioned on **date_m** field. The problem is when I run the above query, it takes more than two days and then it is finished
with this error:

```
ERROR at line 2
ORA-01555 : snapshot too old: rollback segment number 9 with name "_SYSSMU9_1692468413$" too small
ORA-06512 : at line 13
ORA-06512 : at line 13
```

Would you please guid me what is the problem with the query and how to make it run faster?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any relationship between the cursor you're looping across and the update statement, so it looks like you're effectively running the exact same update statement for however many rows there are in the cursor. Is that really what you want to have happen? Also, there isn't a need to use dynamic sql here. As things stand, your procedure should just contain a single update statement - or better yet, a merge statement - with no looping or dynamic sql required.

Comment: @Boneist, thank you for your feedback,two tables have common columns, named **id**.

Comment: yes, I can see that. However, your cursor (`select /*+parallel(10)*/ distinct date_m td from the_table order by td`) isn't referenced at all by the update statement. If it was, I'd expect to see `rec.td` somewhere in the update statement. Since there isn't, and since the udpate statement doesn't change when it is looped around, you're doing the equivalent of "for the first date, run this update, for the second date, run the update again, for the third date, run the update yet again, ...". Once you've run the update, running it again isn't going to do much except waste cpu and time!

Comment: Are you trying to update the table one partition at a time? Because if so, there are better ways of doing so.

Comment: @Boneist, there is mistake in writing the query, I've added *rec.td* to the update. Yes, I want to update the table one partition at a time.

Comment: @M_Gh - that won't work, `rec.td` is out of scope within the dynamic query; you would need to pass it in as a bind variable. (But then as already said it doesn't need to be dynamic). You're comparing that with `date`, which is presumably `date_m`? If so why are you calling `to_date()` on it - that will at best do implicit conversion... Not sure if you've just mangled your real query so much for posting that it's now impossible to tell what you're really doing.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I used **to_date** before using the dynamic query, but I received **ORA-01427**.

Comment: That's nothing to do with static vs. dynamic... and as it implies you have multiple matching rows it'll probably be an issue for the merge too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you couldn't just use a single merge statement to do the job? E.g.:

```
MERGE INTO the_table tgt
USING b_id_list src
  ON (SUBSTR(tgt.id, 12) = to_char(b.id))
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.b_id = src.id
  WHERE tgt.b_id IS NULL
  OR    tgt.b_id != src.b_id;
```

Comment: Thank you,I don't know about *merge*. I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: I have searched about **Merge** and found that it is a kind of risky. Since, it may change all record results. So, I don't use it.

Comment: I have to create the table from scratch, since none of the solutions run with less than 24 hours.

Comment: `MERGE` is risky because it could change all record results?!?! The same argument applies to `UPDATE`! In fact, the merge statement I've given you would only update the matching rows if the target b_id is either null or doesn't match the source b_id, so in fact it would update fewer rows than your original update statement.

Comment: I said based on this post : https://michaeljswart.com/2012/08/be-careful-with-the-merge-statement/

Comment: That's about using `MERGE` on SQL Server. You aren't using SQL Server; you tagged Oracle. Don't expect issues in one database platform to be the same in a completely different one!

Answer (score 0):

To update thee columns of the Oracle table based on Merge, can use this query:

```
MERGE INTO target_table tt
USING base_table st ON (tt.ID = st.id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tt.org_l0 = st.areaid,
           tt.org_l1 = st.manage_id,
           tt.org_l2 = st.b_id;
```